# Reactjs: getting building static html for pages failed

Tags: windows, reactjs, gatsby

I am learning reactjs from gatsby framework where i am trying to change the title of the website by using site.siteMetadata but getting an error as "data is not defined" and also html static pages build failed.

{data.site.siteMetadata.title}
   ^
  error

```html
import React from "react";
import g from "glamorous";
import {css} from "glamour";
import Link from "gatsby-link"
import {rhythm} from "../utils/typography";

const linkstyle=css({float:'right'});
exports.default=
({children})=>
<g.Div margin={'0 auto'}>
maxwidth={700}
padding={rhythm(1.5)}>
<Link to={'/'}>
<g.H3
marginBottom={rhythm(2)}
display={'inline-Block'}
fontStyle={'normal'}>
{data.site.siteMetadata.title}
</g.H3>
</Link>
<Link classname={linkStyle} to={'/about/'}>
About
</Link>
{children()}
</g.Div>
export const query=graphql
'query LayoutQuery{
site{
siteMetadata{
title
}
}
}
## 


----------
```

Comment: Please show us the code that is causing the error

Comment: it is inside the layout i.e    https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-four/  at the end while using siteMetadata in layout/index.js

Comment: Please provide Gatsby version being used as well (as code that @MaxBaldwin) mentioned

Comment: gatsby version 2.0.0

Comment: In your question above, edit it and add your code that is causing the error. Not the tutorial code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `gatsby v2` you should follow the tutorial for v2:
https://next.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-four/

The `children()` isn't valid syntax anymore in Gatsby v2.